# Cones color problems with Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

I am having a small issue when plotting cones with Plotly. In my data, I have 2 types of vectors for norm 1 and 1.5. When I plot just 8 of them on a cube, the colors are rendered very well with each type of vector have one of two colors. But as soon as I go bigger with 2 cubes for example then it becomes quite random. Here is a minimal example that reproduces this issue.

The data:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go

pos=pd.DataFrame([
      [0.0,0.0,0.0],
      [0.5,0.0,0.0],
      [0.0, 0.5,0.0],
      [0.5,0.5,0.0],
      [0.0,0.0,0.5],
      [0.5,0.0,0.5],
      [0.0,0.5,0.5],
      [0.5,0.5,0.5]
      ], columns=['x','y','z'])
pos2=pd.DataFrame([
      [0.0,0.0,0.0],
      [0.5,0.0,0.0],
      [0.0, 0.5,0.0],
      [0.5,0.5,0.0],
      [0.0,0.0,0.5],
      [0.5,0.0,0.5],
      [0.0,0.5,0.5],
      [0.5,0.5,0.5],
      [1.0,0.0,0.0],
      [1.5,0.0,0.0],
      [1.0, 0.5,0.0],
      [1.5,0.5,0.0],
      [1.0,0.0,0.5],
      [1.5,0.0,0.5],
      [1.0,0.5,0.5],
      [1.5,0.5,0.5]
      ], columns=['x','y','z'])
type = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5],[1],[1.5]]), columns=['Type'])
vec = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[ 0.56493151,  0.58643612, -0.5804697 ],
       [ 0.52637789, -0.81556709, -0.24036772],
       [-0.64603163, -0.4828808 ,  0.59115925],
       [-0.42559098,  0.83496509,  0.34886332],
       [ 0.16788166,  0.63197593,  0.75658587],
       [ 0.8961372 , -0.20426566,  0.39397165],
       [-0.08599516, -0.68074558, -0.72745467],
       [-0.90366508,  0.25896575, -0.34106622],
       [ 0.68002417,  0.47929612, -0.55483543],
       [ 0.2721998 ,  0.70224966, -0.65783941],
       [-0.68464335, -0.51281615,  0.5179605 ],
       [-0.35330142, -0.53106658,  0.77015998],
       [-0.46760187,  0.29858559,  0.83198265],
       [ 0.68459979, -0.50165276,  0.52883612],
       [ 0.44722097, -0.32492581, -0.83331664],
       [-0.55474541,  0.49785322, -0.66663311]]), columns=['x','y','z'])
```

Plotting 1 cube:

```
layout = go.Layout(
         title='Cones',
         width=700,
         height=700
        )

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Cone(
    x=pos['x'],
    y=pos['y'],
    z=pos['z'],
    u=type['Type']*vec['x'],
    v=type['Type']*vec['y'],
    w=type['Type']*vec['z'],
    colorscale='viridis',
    colorbar=dict(thickness=20, ticklen=4),
    sizemode="absolute",
    sizeref=0.5,
    anchor='tail'
), layout=layout)

fig
```

[image]

The figure displays the correct color for the 8 vectors.

Plotting 2 cubes:

```
layout = go.Layout(
         title='Cones',
         width=700,
         height=700
        )

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Cone(
    x=pos.append(pos+[1,0,0], ignore_index=True)['x'],
    y=pos.append(pos+[1,0,0], ignore_index=True)['y'],
    z=pos.append(pos+[1,0,0], ignore_index=True)['z'],
    u=type['Type']*vec['x'],
    v=type['Type']*vec['y'],
    w=type['Type']*vec['z'],
    colorscale='viridis',
    colorbar=dict(thickness=20, ticklen=4),
    sizemode="absolute",
    sizeref=0.5,
    anchor='tail'
), layout=layout)

fig
```

[image]

As you can see on this last image, all vectors of norm 1 are dark purple, whereas the vectors of norm 1.5 take a gradient of colors with some even being dark purple as shown by the cone that has its coordinates displayed.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: which plotly version are you running?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a helpful answer, but the best I can make out is you've stumbled on to a bug.  I just updated to the latest (plotly 4.11.0) and I get the same results.

If you pass in a constant for `u`,`v`,`w` it renders correctly:

```py
# using pos df from above
vect=pd.DataFrame(np.full((16, 3), 0.866),columns=['u','v','w'])

fig = go.Figure(data = go.Cone(
                    x=pos.append(pos+[1,0,0], ignore_index=True)['x'],
                    y=pos.append(pos+[1,0,0], ignore_index=True)['y'],
                    z=pos.append(pos+[1,0,0], ignore_index=True)['z'],
                    u=vect['u'],
                    v=vect['v'],
                    w=vect['w'],
                ))

fig.show()
```

[image]

So then I was thinking that maybe the data was getting misaligned (input df's are not always the same size, also side note `pos2` is not used)... BUT, even with your data extracted and put into `vortexTest.csv` I get similar results:

```
x,      y,      z,      u,          v,          w
0,      0,      0,      0.564932,   0.586436,   -0.58047
0.5,    0,      0,      0.789567,   -1.223351,  -0.360552
0,      0.5,    0,      -0.646032,  -0.482881,  0.591159
0.5,    0.5,    0,      -0.638386,  1.252448,   0.523295
0,      0,      0.5,    0.167882,   0.631976,   0.756586
0.5,    0,      0.5,    1.344206,   -0.306398,  0.590957
0,      0.5,    0.5,    -0.085995,  -0.680746,  -0.727455
0.5,    0.5,    0.5,    -1.355498,  0.388449,   -0.511599
1,      0,      0,      0.680024,   0.479296,   -0.554835
1.5,    0,      0,      0.4083,     1.053374,   -0.986759
1,      0.5,    0,      -0.684643,  -0.512816,  0.517961
1.5,    0.5,    0,      -0.529952,  -0.7966,    1.15524
1,      0,      0.5,    -0.467602,  0.298586,   0.831983
1.5,    0,      0.5,    1.0269,     -0.752479,  0.793254
1,      0.5,    0.5,    0.447221,   -0.324926,  -0.833317
1.5,    0.5,    0.5,    -0.832118,  0.74678,    -0.99995
```

```py
df= pd.read_csv("vortexTest.csv")

fig2 = go.Figure(data = go.Cone(
    x=df['x'], y=df['y'], z=df['z'],
    u=df['u'], v=df['v'], w=df['w'],
    cmax=1.5,
    cmin=1
))

fig2.show()
```

[image]

It looks like the `norm` is getting calculated correctly, but somehow the color is not applied right.  As you've pointed out there should only be two colors here, yellow for 1.5 and blue for 1.0.

Comment: Since it seems to be a bug, I will get in touch with Plotly on GitHub and let them know. One thing that works for me for now is to use a bigger system. Adding another cube on the y-direction fixes the problem.